# Problem in Retrieving records by giving from and to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Problem in Retrieving records by giving from and to date. I want to fetch record for date Feb 08 2010, and I should use To and From date fields. I tried:

```
select * from dbo.BuzzMaster
where date >=  '2/7/2010'
  and date <=  '2/8/2010'
```

Output:

```
Not able to retrieve records for date '2/8/2010'
```

I get the record for date '2/8/2010' only if I give:

```
select * from dbo.BuzzMaster
where date >=  '2/7/2010'
  and date <=  '2/9/2010'
```

**(or)**

```
select * from dbo.BuzzMaster
where date >=  '2/8/2010'
  and date <=  '2/9/2010'
```

So how do I do that by selecting date `2/7/2010` and '2/8/2010'?

Thanks in advance.

Naveen

Comment: As @treaschf has said, somehow I think your dates have a time part

Answer (score 4):

Do those dates have a time part as well? If they have, you can get the records for 2/8 like this:

```
WHERE Date >= '2/8/2010' AND Date < '2/9/2010'
```

This is because '2/8/2010 12:34' > '2/8/2010'.

(An other thing is, that I prefer writing the dates in the 'yyyy-mm-dd' format in TSQL, which is not culture sensitive.)

Answer (score 1):

use from this query:

```
select * from dbo.BuzzMaster
where date between '2/7/2010' and '2/8/2010'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the date contains a timepart then you can get the required result by issuing the following TSQL

```
select * from dbo.BuzzMaster 
where DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date))>=  '2/7/2010' 
  and DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date))<=  '2/8/2010'
```

This will extract the date part from your date.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that it cannot use indexes on the Date column.